# How can I call a function that acts like __thiscall, except the caller cleans the stack?

Tags: x86, c++, calling-conventions

I'm trying to call a function with a function pointer in C++, but I can't find any convention that fits it. Its stack arguments are (right to left):

```
func(float x, float y, int unk);
```

...but ecx needs to be pointing to a buffer it can use for output / storage. That would be __thiscall, but the caller cleans up the stack (adds 12 to esp). This is what I have right now:

```
((void(__thiscall*)(char*,float,float,int))(0x1234567))(a, b, c);
```

but it causes the application to crash because the stack isn't evened.

How can I call this?

Comment: that sounds more like a fastcall, if ecx points to an integer store

Comment: are you *sure* ecx is used to pass the buffer and not the class instance? please post a fragment of assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a variadic `__thiscall` function (printf-like). Those use `ecx` for `this` but the remaining arguments are pushed onto the stack and the caller cleans it up.